# Solution of extension of six ball puzzle

Tags: information

A quant interview problem:

We have $2n$ identical size balls containing $n$ colors. For each color there are two balls, one ball is heavy and the other is light. All heavy balls weigh the same. All light balls weigh the same. How many weighings on a beam balance are necessary to identify all of the heavy balls?
I know how to calculate the result for $n=3$, like we start with colors = $[\text{white}, \text{red}, \text{blue}]$. Then the first time we weigh $\text{white}_1, \text{red}_2$ comparing to $\text{white}_2$ and $\text{blue}_1$. So depending on the first outcome, we only need 2 weighs at most. But how about $2n$?

Comment: In your example of $n=3$, I dont understand the first weighting.

Comment: For $n=3$, you can group them into same weight balls with two tries but not sure how you can identify the weight.

Comment: ah there is a typo, it's 'white_2' and 'blue_1'

Comment: @XuShan For $n =3$, I still don't know how 2 weighting is sufficient for identify all the 6 ball.

Comment: if left = right, i.e. white_1, red_2 = white_2, blue_1. It means that red_2 and blue_1 has different weight. Then we try weight red_2 with red_1. If red_2 is heavier, then blue_1 is lighter one, and also white_1 is lighter one. If left < right, i.e. white_1, red_2 < white_2, blue_1. This means white_1 < white_2. But red_2 and blue_1 are not so sure. so we try another chance for red_2 and red_1. @NN2

Comment: @XuShan this technique for $n = 3$ is Interesting!

Comment: well so now I am asking for a general solution of n @NN2